# why date picker not showing red border in angularjs + bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularjs with bootstrap .I have one invalid field in form .I need to make red it border when it is invalid (text become red).there is a class in bootstrap `.has-error`

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#callout-form-validation-state-accessibility

here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/neixp9ZARRAQ33gKSV9u?p=preview
[image]

My field is **invalid** but border is not red and text is not red,why ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and _the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined anywhere what should happen when the field is invalid.

Angular is adding the class "ng-invalid" when the field is not correct, so you might add this code to your css to get a red border when the input is incorrect:

```
.form-control.ng-invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the class inside the span, put `text-danger` in place of `help-block`. It's the class from bootstrap that refere to an invalid field.

```
<span id="" ng-if="userForm[key].$invalid" class="text-danger" style="margin-bottom:0">Invalid date </span>
```